# Cannot establish HTTP/2 connection from OkHTTP/ALPN/Linux client with Apache HTTP

Tags: linux, apache, http2, okhttp, alpn

Problem which I have is Linux related, as it does not occur when the same HTTP2 client runs from Windows.

```
$java -jar -Xbootclasspath/p:alpn-boot-8.1.9.v20160720.jar SampleOkHttp-1.0.jar https://192.168.1.10:8080/simple.html
```

HTTP/2 preface communication:

Windows

```
>> CONNECTION 505249202a20485454502f322e300d0a0d0a534d0d0a0d0a
>> 0x00000000     6 SETTINGS
>> 0x00000000     4 WINDOW_UPDATE
<< 0x00000000     6 SETTINGS
<< 0x00000000     4 WINDOW_UPDATE
>> 0x00000003    69 HEADERS       END_STREAM|END_HEADERS
>> 0x00000000     0 SETTINGS      ACK
<< 0x00000000     0 SETTINGS      ACK
<< 0x00000003    86 HEADERS       END_HEADERS
<< 0x00000003   220 DATA          END_STREAM
h2
<< 0x00000000     8 GOAWAY
```

Linux

```
>> CONNECTION 505249202a20485454502f322e300d0a0d0a534d0d0a0d0a
>> 0x00000000     6 SETTINGS      
>> 0x00000000     4 WINDOW_UPDATE 
>> 0x00000003    69 HEADERS       END_STREAM|END_HEADERS
<< 0x00000000     6 SETTINGS      
>> 0x00000000     0 SETTINGS      ACK
<< 0x00000000     8 GOAWAY        
<< 0x00000000     4 WINDOW_UPDATE 
<< 0x00000000     8 GOAWAY
```

Tried with Ubuntu\Fedora, from local\remote machine, with different java\alpn versions. I'm still getting GOAWAY.
Why Apache in case of Linux sends GOAWAY message? How to fix it?

Comment: The GOAWAY frame contains an error code and optional debug data, could you dump those? https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7540#section-6.8

Comment: Is there an easy way to get debug data by okhttp library?

Answer (score 1):

Problem occurred during cipher key negotiation.

Windows with TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 had no issue.

Linux was rejected because tried to use TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA.

I solved issue by providing acceptable cipher keys in Apache config file conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf described [here](https://icing.github.io/mod_h2/howto.html#https).

In short I changed default settings for **SSLCipherSuite** on:

```
SSLCipherSuite ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!3DES:!MD5:!PSK
```